# having problem with use dispatch in redux

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux-toolkit

I try to get firestore database and dispatch this database in redux. and print this database in my listpage.
I succeed to get firestore database, and console.log are print all data. but I try to use map() function. print only one data. I don't know why this had happened.
I think my code is wrong. but I don't know where I got it wrong.

DictCard.js

```js
import { collection, getDocs} from "firebase/firestore";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { db } from "../firebase"; 
import { useSelector, useDispatch  } from "react-redux";
import { getDict } from "../redux/ListReducer";

const Card = ({dict}) => {
    return(
        <div className="inbox">
            <p className="text1">단어</p>
            <p className="text2">{dict.word}</p>
            <p className="text1">설명</p>
            <p className="text2">{dict.explain}</p>
            <p className="text1">예시</p>
            <p className="text2" style={{color:"lightskyblue",paddingBottom:"0"}}>{dict.example}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

const DictCard = () => {
    const dictList = useSelector((state) => state.dictList.dicts);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect( async () => {
        const query = await getDocs(collection(db, "dict"));
        query.forEach(doc => {
            console.log([doc.id, doc.data()])
            dispatch(getDict([{id: doc.id, text: doc.data()}]))
        });
    },[]);


    return(
        <div className="dict-card" >
            {dictList.map((dict) => (
                <Card dict = {dict.text} key = {dict.id}/>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default DictCard;
```

ListReducer.js

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

// const initialState = [{id:"",text:{word:"",explain:"",example:""}}]

const initState = {
    dicts: [{
        id:"",
        text:{
            word:"",
            explain:"",
            example:""
        }
    },]
}

export const ListReducer = createSlice({
    name: "dictList",
    initialState: initState,
    reducers: {
        addDict: (state, action) => {
            state.dicts = action.payload
        },
        getDict: (state, action) => {
            state.dicts = action.payload
        },
        updateDict: (state, action) => {
        },
        deleteDict:  (state, action) => {
        },
    },
});

export const { addDict, getDict, updateDict, deleteDict } = ListReducer.actions;

export default ListReducer.reducer;
```

I think dispatch's position is wrong but i have no idea

Comment: can you share your code in codesandbox

Answer (score 2):

I solved problem.

```js
 useEffect( async () => {
        const arr = []
        const query = await getDocs(collection(db, "dict"));
        query.forEach(doc => {
            console.log([doc.id, doc.data()])
            // dispatch(getDict([{id: doc.id, text: doc.data()}]))
            arr.push({id: doc.id, text: doc.data()})
        });
        dispatch(getDict(arr))
    },[]);
```

need to make empty array

Comment: query.forEach(({id, data})=> { arr.push({id, text: data()})....

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use `async function` for `useEffect`

> ```
> useEffect(() => {
>     const fetchData = async () => {
>         const query = await getDocs(collection(db, "dict"));
>         query.forEach(doc => {
>             console.log([doc.id, doc.data()])
>             dispatch(getDict([{id: doc.id, text: doc.data()}]))
>         });
>     }
>     fetchData()
> },[]);
> ```

I think the issue may caused from the `useEffect` function. If it not, please comment below so i can track the issue more clearly